# $B=\{f \in C[0,1] : \sup_{x\in [0,1]} |f(x)| \leq 1\}$, $\Gamma \in C^{*}$ but $\Gamma(B)$ is open

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

> Let $C$ be the Banach space of all complex continuous functions on $[0,1]$, with the supremum norm. Let $B$ be the closed unit ball of $C$. Show that there exists continuous linear functionals $\Gamma$ on $C$ for which $\Gamma(B)$ is an open subset of the complex plane ; in particular, $|\Gamma|$ attains no maximum on $B$.

This is the problem in the book 'Rudin's fuctional analysis', p$87$ problem $8$.

By duality, $\Gamma$ can be expressed as follows.

$$\Gamma(f)=\int_{[0,1]}f(x) \, d\mu(x)$$
for some regular Borel measure $\mu$.

The typical example is a point mass measure, but it doesn't work. I have no idea.

(I'm calculating the case that $\mu(1/n)=(1/2)^n(-1)^n, n=1,2,3,4,...$)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Take something that would require a jump to attain the norm.

Comment: @DanielFischer What's a sparation?

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier. A typo that up to a couple of moments ago nobody had fixed ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**.
Try $$ \Gamma(x) = \int_0^{1/2} x(t) \, dt - \int_{1/2}^1 x(t) \, dt $$